# Can I use Facebook's Groups For Schools to verify if someone is a student or not?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Can I use the Facebook API to get which users belong to Facebook's groups for schools product? And is this a reliable way of verifying if someone is a student or not?

Answer (score 1):

*Is this a reliable way of verifying if someone is a student or not?*

No.

I present you with a simple counter-example. Facebook's [Groups for Schools](https://www.facebook.com/about/groups/schools) uses .edu email addresses for validation.  I've not been a student for about twenty years. I still have an active .edu account. Silly university!

Additionally, many educational institutions (US secondary and pre-secondary schools, I'm thinking of) don't offer email addresses.

Now, if you're looking for a rough measure, it may be good enough.

Comment: Assuming groups for schools is good enough, does Facebook let you see this part of user's data? I know we can see groups, but how to distinguish groups for schools vs other groups?